# Break parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a menu and submenu which have 200px of width each.
The parent of the menu has 250px of width. when the content of parent menu is too long, submenu cannot be shown entirely.
I'd like the sliding submenu be entirely shown ! [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Barhamada/upece9te/33/) is an example

```css
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dad {
  width: 250px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<div class="dad">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul class="parent-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Electronics</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Clothing</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Books</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">T&C</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean when the content of parent menu is too long, submenu cannot be shown entirely, don`t you?

Comment: @LeoZhao Yes that's the matter

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:auto` and add `position:relative` to `#menu` and use `left:0` to your second level `ul`.

```css
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dad {
  width: 250px;
}
#menu {
  //  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<div class="dad">


  <nav id="menu">
    <ul class="parent-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Electronics</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Clothing</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Books</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">T&C</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```